# Searching through AD for existing hostname and error checking

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am writing a script to configure IP address, hostname and join the domain after the build. I want to run the script from a non-domain joined PC. There are two things that I would like to do:

- search the hostname if it exists or not and if not then throw an error
- join the domain and if the password is incorrect then don't join.

```
Write-Host "Please enter your desired computer name: [Default $env:computername]"
$computername = Read-Host

Write-Host "If this computer object exists in AD, make sure the computer it is deleted or domain join will fail!" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Sleep -Seconds 2

$renamecomputer = $true
if ($computername -eq "" -or $computername -eq $env:computername) {
    $computername = $env:computername;
    $renamecomputer = $false
}

$dompassword = Read-Host "Enter the domain administrator password for the host to join the domain" -AsSecureString

$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("domain\domainadmin", $dompassword )
Write-Host "Adding $computername to the domain"
Add-Computer -DomainName "domain.local" -Credential $credentials -OUPath $ou

if ($renamecomputer -eq $true) {
    Rename-Computer -NewName $computername -DomainCredential $credentials -Force
}
```

Can anyone please suggest/modify the code such that it can do some error checking of hostname existing and password incorrect.

Comment: It is definitely a good idea to rename the computer __before__ joining it to Domain or, I believe `Add-Computer` allows you to choose a new name altogether.

Comment: You can definitely use `add-computer` and the `-newname` variable to but that doesn't solve the problem of error checking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple try/catch you can implement.

In the catch statement you can rename the computer with a variable or prompt for a new name.

```
$NEWcomputername = "computername114"

try {
    $computer = Get-ADComputer $NEWcomputername
    $name = $computer.Name
    # If we get here, we know it exists
    # You can rename your new machine here if you want
    Write-Host "$name already exists"
}
catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException]
{
    # Whatever you last tried doesn't exist you can join it to the domain in these catch
    write-host "doesn't exist "
}
```

Comment: Are you sure a non-domain joined computer can query the domain?

Comment: You are correct. This wouldn't work from the non-joined machine.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I would like a similar code to access AD from a non-domain PC.